# Utilizing Logging checker when logger is an object attribute

Tags: python, pylint

I've been trying to configure PyLint to check for [logging-not-lazy](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#logging-checker) using PyLint 1.3.1. In the Trac project we have cases in which the logger is an attribute of an object.

For example, an `Environment` object is [passed to the initializer](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.1/trac/wiki/model.py?marks=35-36#L30) and later the logger is utilized through a call [self.env.log(...)](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.1/trac/wiki/model.py?marks=98-99#L89). I haven't had any success getting PyLint to detect the instances of string interpolation when running `pylint --disable=all --enable=logging --logging-modules=self.env.log trac/wiki/model.py`.

PyLint has no problem detecting the following case:

```
from trac.log import logger_factory
log = logger_factory()
log.info('Deleted version %d of page %s'
         % (version, self.name))
```

Comment: you should rather create an issue on pylint's bug tracker on bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issues (check if some similar one exists first!)

Comment: Create [ticket 459](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint/issue/459/support-logging-check-when-logger-is-an).